# What is the difference between Implementation datatype and application datatype in Arxml(Autosar)?

Tags: xml, embedded, autosar

If both are same, why we have different names IDT and ADT?
Can someone explain this topic IDT and ADT briefly please?

Comment: If both are same then AUTOSAR won't create different names for same concept.Check [5.2 Data Types](https://www.autosar.org/fileadmin/user_upload/standards/classic/20-11/AUTOSAR_TPS_SoftwareComponentTemplate.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

The main goal of the ApplicationDataType is the description of the physical properties (unit, physical dimension, conversion between internal and physical value).

The ImplementationDataType is all about the configuration of language-specific data types. In tis spirit, ImplementationDataType is used to configure C data types on the AUTOSAR classic platform while CppImplementationDataType is used for the description of C++ data types on the AUTOSAR adaptive platform.

I‘d recommend to read the chapter 5 of the document [„AUTOSAR Software Component Template“](https://www.autosar.org/fileadmin/user_upload/standards/classic/21-11/AUTOSAR_TPS_SoftwareComponentTemplate.pdf) that introduces the levels of data type definition in the AUTOSAR standard and provides more background information.

Answer (score 0):

Application Data Types are defined on vehicle, system architecture or software architecture level, Implementation Data Types at software architecture or software design level.

The Application Data Types allow you to specify physical units, ranges, accuracy/ suggested resolution, enumeration entries and also maps, curves and the like.

However, they do not specify your actual data type in C and the scaling between physical and machine level value.

For this you then have the Implementation Data Types, which give you this.